# Control fanlight with both remote and switch

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

I would like to control my fan using remote and the light on the fan using both remote and switch. Is that possible.

I have 1 black wire, 1 red wire for light, neutral and ground wire coming from the ceiling. I have capped the red wire and connected the black wire to the remote receiver. I am able to control the fan using remote. I connected the black wire to single pole switch to control the power to the fan.

I heard using external relay, we can achieve the above functionality. Don't know how to implement. Could someone please guide me ?

Comment: Do you want dimming control of the fan light? What make and model of fan remote are you using, and are you OK with taking it back and getting a different one?

Answer (score 0):

The receiver for the remote needs power to work, so you can't fully control it with the switch and the remote.  When the switch is off, the receiver will not have any power so it can't turn anything on. So, at a minimum, the switch can turn the light off, but in order to use the remote, you would have to turn the switch on.

Another possibility is to not use the included remote and instead power the fan with some "smart" switches that can be controlled with their own remote.  Doing it that way means the switch on the wall "is" the remote, so you can control the fan and light two ways.

Comment: I have two hot wire (black and red), I can power the receiver with black wire (always on) and connect the red wire to a switch.

Comment: That is true, and you could try that, but the remote receiver might not like to get voltage on it's output wire when it should be "off" (receiver powered but off, and red wire switch on).  If the receiver was designed well, it shouldn't be an issue, but there is a chance it could damage it.